# Need help for project of video with over layers

Tags: video, streaming, overlay, layer, software-design

I'm so shame to do this question, but really, I waste a bunch of years thinking that I can do this.
I start this project on as2 (yes, actionscript 2), then as3... In this language I can put a video player on the first layer an then I animate over the layers I want (Enough for me). I put logos, graphic animations, calculate the intro and outro, make the mix, etc, and my only worry was my GPU, but I have a good one. The thing is that as was a dead end.

So, on this darkest times, hope you can guide me to what code I can use for this project.
Also, I really don't understand why actioscript disappear.

Answer (score 0):

with HTML and Javascript you can place a video on a canvas, and then apply other actions to the canvas.

You can see my example app at [chyron.a.video](https://chyron.a.video), where an image and text (a 'chyron' are the words like on a news broadcast) are overlaid on a video.

here's my screen with an image, and a banner of text using the app:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The code then can either broadcast the resulting video as a livestream, or save the video and upload as a video on demand - these use [api.video](https://api.video) for the video delivery.

here's the video I recorded:
https://embed.api.video/vod/vi6sVqRlo84gtOmje5FxL0V9
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpknO.png

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!! I'm gonna take a look now. Because the last time I check only accept 1 layer on video on full screen. I get back to you soon..thks!